# Problem with Ubuntu 14.04 - gnome tweak tool

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I don't have an "extension" and a "change shell theme" section.

[image: Image of the tweak tool]

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the screenshot shows, you are running the Unity desktop environment. To tweak this you need the **Unity Tweak Tool**. GNOME Extensions and the **GNOME Tweak Tool** are for the GNOME desktop environment ... so - if you want to see and use GNOME Extensions you will have to install the GNOME desktop environment first. Alternatively you can install the Ubuntu GNOME edition. To install the GNOME desktop environment  - open a terminal - execute the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```